# sorting words in python

Tags: python

Is it possible in python to sort a list of words not according to the english alphabet but according to a self created alphabet.

Comment: what is self-created alphabet?

Answer (score 13):

You can normally define custom comparison methods so the sort is performed within your restrictions. I've never coded a line of Python in my life, but it's similar enough to Ruby for me to notice that the following excerpt from [this page](http://refactormycode.com/codes/179-custom-sort-a-list-of-words) might help you:

```
alphabet = "zyxwvutsrqpomnlkjihgfedcba"

inputWords = ["england", "france", "spain", "italy", "greece", "portugal",
              "canada", "usa", "mexico", "peru", "cuba", "chile", "argentina",
              "zimbabwe", "uganda", "congo", "zambia", "namibia", "ghana"]

print sorted(inputWords, key=lambda word: [alphabet.index(c) for c in word])
```

You might also want to check out [these](http://www.universalwebservices.net/web-programming-resources/python/advanced-sorting-techniques) [articles](http://icfun.blogspot.com/2009/08/python-customize-sorting-with.html). Good luck!