# sorting of list containing utf-8 characters

Tags: python, sorting, utf-8

The beginning of question is here [Custom sort python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645986/custom-sort-python/10657058#10657058)

I want to make special sorting by this alphabet

```
alphabet = u'aáàAâÂbBcCçÇdDeéEfFgGğĞhHiİîÎíīıIjJkKlLmMnNóoOöÖpPqQrRsSşŞtTuUûúÛüÜvVwWxXyYzZ
```

[aáàAâÂ] **this group of characters should have same priority**. In earlier thread,  @happydave suggested to use (alphabet.index(c)/2),

> which should map each pair of adjacent characters in your list to the
>   same priority.

But in my case I don't have pair of character? for example: aáàAâÂ, eéE, uUûúÛ, óoO, iİîÎíī.

In my opinion simple way is to add one item,containing only paired charachers to each list, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
 [['word1', <Element tag at b719a4cc>], ['word2', <Element tag at b719a6cc>]]
```

list of list with one added item

```
[['word1_', 'word1', <Element tag at b719a4cc>], ['word2_', 'word2', <Element tag at b719a6cc>]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s='aáàAâÂbBcCçÇdDeéEfFgGğĞhHiİîÎíīıIjJkKlLmMnNóoOöÖpPqQrRsSşŞtTuUûúÛüÜvVwWxXyYzZ'
s2='aaaaaabbccccddeeeffgggghhiiiiiiiijjkkllmmnnoooooppqqrrssssttuuuuuuuvvwwxxyyzz'
trans = str.maketrans(s, s2)

def unikey(seq):
    return seq[0].translate(trans)
```

Use this function as `key` argument of `sorted`

Comment: Thank you! That is just as I imagined the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Too much work. [Set your locale](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html), and then [`key=locale.strxfrm`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.strxfrm).

And never sort UTF-8 characters; always decode to `unicode` first.

Comment: Doesn't matter terribly. Most Latin-based locales should DTRT.

Comment: Thank you @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams. I'll read the documentation, but I really lack experience in python.