# Sorting string values according to a custom alphabet in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I am looking for an efficient way to sort a list of strings according a custom alphabet.

For example, I have a string alphabet which is `"bafmxpzv"` and a list of strings composed from only the characters contained in that alphabet.

I would like a way to sort that list similarly to other common sorts, but using this custom alphabet. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom sort python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645986/custom-sort-python)

Comment: wow, in the linked question, I found this piece of code I do not understand well but it seems to work: new_list = sorted(inputList, key=lambda word: [alphabet.index(c) for c in word[0]]) ------ why word[0]???? cant understand that

Comment: clearly, just "word" should be there

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Let's create an alphabet and a list of words:

```
In [32]: alphabet = "bafmxpzv"

In [33]: a = ['af', 'ax', 'am', 'ab', 'zvpmf']
```

Now let's sort them according to where the letters appear in `alphabet`:

```
In [34]: sorted(a, key=lambda word: [alphabet.index(c) for c in word])
Out[34]: ['ab', 'af', 'am', 'ax', 'zvpmf']
```

The above sorts in the correct order.

`sorted` enables a wide range of custom sorting.  The `sorted` function has three optional arguments: `cmp`, `key`, and `reverse`:

- `cmp` is good for complex sorting tasks.  If specified, `cmp` should be a functionIt that takes two arguments.  It should return a negative, zero or positive number depending on whether the first argument is considered smaller than, equal to, or larger than the second argument.  For this case, `cmp` is overkill.
- `key`, if spedified, should be a function that takes one argument and returns something that python knows natively how to sort. In this case, key returns a list of the indices of each of the word's characters in the alphabet.

  In this case, `key` returns the index of a letter in `alphabet`.
- `reverse`, if true, reverses the sort-order.

#### A nonworking alternative

From the comments, this alternative form was mentioned:

```
In [35]: sorted(a, key=lambda word: [alphabet.index(c) for c in word[0]])
Out[35]: ['af', 'ax', 'am', 'ab', 'zvpmf']
```

Note that this does not sort in the correct order.  That is because the `key` function here only considers the first letter of each word.  This can be demonstrated by testing `key`:

```
In [2]: key=lambda word: [alphabet.index(c) for c in word[0]]

In [3]: key('af')
Out[3]: [1]

In [4]: key('ax')
Out[4]: [1]
```

Observe that `key` returns the same value for two different strings, `af` and `ax`.  The value returned reflects only the first character of each word. Because of this, `sorted` has no way of determining that `af` belongs before `ax`.

Comment: Great solution!  
Minor correction:  "In this case, key returns the index of a letter in alphabet." should be: "In this case, key returns a list with an entry for each character in word reflecting the character's index in alphabet."

Comment: @Jpsy Thanks and I reworded that sentence!

Comment: How could this be applied to sort based on a sub-string within the string? For example if `a = ['01af', '02ax', '03am', '04ab', '05zvpmf']`, so the list is only sorted by alphabetic characters only

Comment: @IMLD It isn't clear to me exactly what you want but try: `sorted(a, key=lambda word: [alphabet.index(c) for c in word if c.isalpha()])`

Answer (score 2):

Update, I misread your question, you have a list of strings, not a single string, here's how to do it, the idea is the same, use a sort based on a custom comparison function:

```
def acmp (a,b):
 la = len(a)
 lb = len(b)
 lm = min(la,lb)
 p = 0
 while p < lm:
    pa = alphabet.index(a[p])
    pb = alphabet.index(b[p])
    if pa > pb:
        return 1
    if pb > pa:
        return -1
    p = p + 1

 if la > lb:
    return 1
 if lb > la:
    return -1
 return 0

mylist = ['baf', 'bam', 'pxm']
mylist.sort(cmp = acmp)
```

Comment: how can you call sort on a string?

Comment: oops it doesn't have sort, use sorted then, thanks for correction.  I'ved edited the answer

Comment: on second thought, I think I miss-understood his original questions.  It is a list of strings, not just a string.  I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `index()` which requires finding the index of a char, a better alternative consists in building a hash map to be used in the sorting, in order to retrieve the index directly.
Example:

```
>>> alphabet = "bafmxpzv"
>>> a = ['af', 'ax', 'am', 'ab', 'zvpmf']
>>> order = dict(zip(alphabet, range(len(alphabet))))
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda word: [order[c] for c in word])
['ab', 'af', 'am', 'ax', 'zvpmf']
```

Comment: I would replace line 3 with `order = { ch : i for i, ch in enumerate(alphabet) }`; though I suppose that's up to personal preference.