# sort array based on custom alphabet order python

Tags: python, sorting

I want to write a code to sort arr based on customAl order, and not use sorted function.

```
customAl = [dshbanfmg]
arr = [bba,abb,baa,mggfba,mffgh......]
```

psudo code:

```
def sortCA(arr, customAl):
    dt = {}
    generate dt order based on customAl
    look up and sort arr

    return result


newArr = [bba,baa,abb,mffgh,mggfba......]
```

I know there's a similiar question but the answer is wrapped in sorted function which I don't wish to use. anyone has a better solution than unsorted, or dictionary which takes space?

[Sorting string values according to a custom alphabet in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579392/sorting-string-values-according-to-a-custom-alphabet-in-python)

Comment: I think the solution you linked to is a good solution. It doesn't even use dictionaries. It does use a key for sorting though (that's unrelated to dictionary keys).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting string values according to a custom alphabet in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579392/sorting-string-values-according-to-a-custom-alphabet-in-python)

Comment: As I stated in my post, I am not looking for answers that use sorted function. That defeats the purpose of posting this thread.

Comment: @Sailormoon Why not use `sorted`? Would `list.sort` work instead?

Comment: None of the names like `dshbanfmg` and `bba` are not defined in your example. Are they supposed to be strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, programming is a trade-off, it depends on which part you care most.

Specifically, in this scenario, you can choose to trade time for space by `str.index`, or you can trade space for time with an extra index `dict`:

```
customAl = 'dshbanfmg'
arr = ['bba', 'abb', 'baa', 'mggfba', 'mffgh']

# trade time for space
# no extra space but, but O(n) to index
def sortCA1(arr, customAl):
    return sorted(arr, key=lambda x: [customAl.index(c) for c in x])

# trade space for time
# extra space O(n), but O(1) to index
def sortCA2(arr, customAl):
    dt = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(customAl)}
    return sorted(arr, key=lambda x: [dt[c] for c in x])

# output: ['bba', 'baa', 'abb', 'mffgh', 'mggfba']
```

---

Here is a version which not use `sorted` function, we can use a bucket based on custom alphabet order. split the arr by 1st char, if one bucket has multiple elements then split by 2nd char recursively...kind of radix sort:
one thing to mention, the length is different, so we should add a bucket to record none index str.

```
def sortCA3(arr, customAl):
    dt = {c: i + 1 for i, c in enumerate(customAl)}  # keep 0 for none bucket

    def bucket_sort(arr, start):
        new_arr = []
        buckets = [[] for _ in range(len(customAl) + 1)]

        for s in arr:
            if start < len(s):
                buckets[dt[s[start]]].append(s)
            else:
                buckets[0].append(s)

        for bucket in buckets:
            if len(bucket) == 1:
                new_arr += bucket
            elif len(bucket) > 1:
                new_arr += bucket_sort(bucket, start+1)
        return new_arr

    return bucket_sort(arr, 0)
```

test and output

```
customAl = 'dshbanfmg'
arr = ['bba', 'bb', 'abb', 'baa', 'mggfba', 'mffgh']  # add `bb` for test
print(sortCA4(arr, customAl))
```

Comment: Hi @recnac, i want to find a solution that doesn't use sorted function.

Comment: Hi, @Sailormoon, I have added a new solution without `sorted`, use bucket

Comment: bucket sort is perfect for this type @recnac