# Sort words based on first letter in text file, python

Tags: python

This is the function to read words from text file, sort these and then store in another text file.

```
#file contains words
file=open('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Post_OCR_Classifictaion/Dict_try.txt').read().split()

#sorting order based on letters
letters="abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyz"
d={i:letters.index(i) for i in letters}

#sort function
sorted_list=sorted(file,key=d.get)

#store after sortting in new file
textfile = open("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Post_OCR_Classifictaion/Dict_try_sort.txt", "w")
for element in sorted_list:
    textfile.write(element + "\n")
textfile.close()
```

These are the words in text file:

aço

çzb

ogğ

beg

zğe

öge

ğg

gaço

ogğ

But it gives error:

[image]

Comment: seems dictionary doesn't have values, throws none which cant be given to sort function

Please use filter to filter all Nones in list

Comment: It do sort if there are just letters in text file but for words it is throwing this error.

Comment: Your dict is consisted of one-letter strings. Not a single word will be in that dict so `get` will return `None`. Why do you need a `key` for the sort? That's already the default...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting string values according to a custom alphabet in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579392/sorting-string-values-according-to-a-custom-alphabet-in-python)

Comment: Be careful: `Dict_try.txt` is not closed.

Comment: @qouify See [Is explicitly closing files important?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7395542/6045800) for more details and refinement of my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

`sorted_list=sorted(file,key=d.get)`

`file` is `list` of *words* whilst `d` is `dict` with keys being *letters*. You need first retrieve first letter of word then search for it in `dict`, for example using `lambda` i.e.

```
sorted_list=sorted(file,key=lambda word:d[word[0]])
```

Comment: That will not sort the words starting with the same letter

Comment: This worked for me but when I used it for more words file it is giving KeyError: '\u202a'. why is this?

Comment: @maryammehboob Because you have characters in the file that are not in the dict... Please note that the above code will not inter-sort words starting with the same letter...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your words to indexes:

```py
def key(word):
    return tuple(d[x] for x in word)
sorted_list = sorted(file, key=key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try to account for both upper and lower case and also any circumstance where the line in 'file' either has a length of zero or starts with a character that is not in your list. Consider this possible solution:-

```
letters = "abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyz"
letters = letters.upper() + letters

def myfunc(s):
    try:
        return letters.index(s[0])
    except Exception:
        pass
    return -1


ml = ['ğc', 'öp', 'Rr', 'Po', 'aw', 'tp', 'çd']
mls = sorted(ml, key=myfunc)
print(mls)
```

The output of this would be:-

['Po', 'Rr', 'aw', 'çd', 'ğc', 'öp', 'tp']