# How do I sort a list of words in alphabetical order from a custom alphabet?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to make a language and to alphabetically sort the words in it, I'm making a python script for it because I can't make things easy for myself. I need to sort it with the alphabet: `"æǽaàbdyýeéfgiíʒklmnŋΩΏoóøǿɤprʃsþðtʊuúʌvɯjz"`.

I tried the top answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579392/sorting-string-values-according-to-a-custom-alphabet-in-python)

```py
def sortA(l, alphabet="AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"):
    returnVal = sorted(l, key=lambda word: [alphabet.index(c) for c in word])
    return returnVal


keys = sortA(keys, "æǽaàbdyýeéfgiíʒklmnŋΩΏoóøǿɤprʃsþðtʊuúʌvɯjz")
```

and vsc says

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
substring not found
  File "filepath", line 13, in <lambda>
    returnVal = sorted(l, key=lambda word: [alphabet.index(c) for c in word])
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

### EDIT

The issue is probably an issue with the encoding of certain characters.

### EDIT 2

I belive the issue is from here:

```
def newEntry():
    word = input("What is the word?: \n")
    defin = input("What is the definition of the word?: \n")
    etymology = input("Where does the word come from?:\n")
    detail = [defin, etymology]
    return {word: detail}

def entryToDict(e):
    spl = str(e).split("\n")
    return [spl[0], [spl[1],spl[2]]]



Read = (f.read()).split("\n\n")
dic = newEntry()
for i in Read:
    entry = entryToDict(i)
    dic[entry[0]] = entry[1]
keys = list(dic.keys())
f.close()
```

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with your inputs, what are your inputs like, do all of them have the same characters as your `alphabet` string?

Comment: Did you try printing `keys`? If there is a value there that is not in your `alphabet` then it can lead to this error

Comment: Your example doesn' work because keys is both input and output of the function and you've not provided an input example. But if I just set it to a string consisting of chars from your vocab then it works fine for me.

Comment: Actually, any Latin characters will cause the error he has posted.  His sort function ONLY handles the letters in the passed alphabet.

Comment: @nokla yes I think that's it, the input much contain out of vocab characters.

Comment: @Suraj Shourie Yes, I'm using a custom keyboard for the inputs.

Comment: @nokla I just tried that, and it outputted ['æovʌn', 'É¯aÊƒoid', 'dfsÊƒia'] but I don't know why.

Comment: We need to see the value of `keys`. "madden", "king" and "bland" all work. "bland king" does not work because space is not included in the custom alphabet. Anything with capital letters won't work either because the custom alphabet only has lower-case. The default alphabet does have capitals but also needs a space.

Comment: Can you please edit the post to include `keys=...` before calling `sortA` so we can see what you're passing as input.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth `keys` is the list of entries already in a separate text file and a new input. While testing I use random gibberish in my alphabet.

Comment: For all the people asking what `keys` is, `keys = ['mægnʌ', 'gløsΩs', 'leksikΩs']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting list according to corresponding values from a parallel list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-according-to-corresponding-values-from-a-parallel-list)

Comment: The best way to do this depends on what operating system you are using, but the most cross-platform approach is to write a set of collation rules and then use `icu.RuleBasedCollator` to create a collator instance you can use with `sort` or `sorted`. There is insufficient in formation in the question to  write those rules, those. Are characters with diacritics primary or secondary weight?  Is casing `a <<< A` or `A<<<a`? Why use Greek omega, rather than Latin omega? Why are the omegas uppercase when everything else is lowercase? What other distinctions exist in the alphabetical sort?

Comment: Also better to swap the rams horn for the Latin gamma.

Comment: @Andj 1. Characters with diacritics **are** weighted less than characters without.    2. There are no capital letters in my language and I'm going to be the only one using this script.                                                                                                                      3. The Latin Omega and lowercase Greek Omega look too similar to a Double-u.      4. I'm not sure what you mean by "other distinctions".                                                5. The Latin Gamma looks too tall and strange, and I don't like it.

Comment: so no tertiary weights, only secondary weights. fairly routine. Diacritic display on omega different to other characters. Since you have mixed scripts in alphabet and trying to use bicameral, as unicameral, best to only ever use the script in text  editors, limit the type of string operations you use on them. Better yet assign your alphabet to PUA codepoints, and update an opensource font to use those codepoints. It will avoid unncessary and unindented changes to text. Unless it is rarely used alphabet, with limited use and no processing.

Comment: @MildlyIntelligent, æ is obviously primary weight (strength 1), but are ʒ, ŋ, Ω, Ώ, ø, ǿ, ɤ, ,ʃ, þ, ð, ʊ, ʌ, and ɯ primary or secondary weight?

Comment: @Andj I don't understand.

Comment: ok, the easiest way is to think of what a dictionary would be like. for instance you have the minimal pairs __àt__ and __az__, which should sort first, should all words starting with __a__ sort before words with __à__ or should they be interfiled, ie. should order be __àt__, __az__ or should it be __az__, __àt__. The first would  be from __à__ having a strength of 2 (ie it is equivalent to __a__ when compared to other letters, but is differentiated form __a__ when compared to __a__. The second sort order is form __à__ having a strength of 1 (primary distinction) .

Comment: A primary distinction would be a letter in its own right, a secondary distinction isn't. obviously the same happens for all letters with a diacritic. But the remaining letters need to be specified. A secondary weight would be `'at', 'àt', 'az'`, a primary distinction would be `'at', 'az', 'àt'`. Same logic needs to apply to other extended Latin letters. With  `ʊuúʌ`  are `ʊuʌ` independent letters having primary distinction, or are they related. Same for other characters.

Comment: Your current code gives every character primary strength which would give you the sort 'at', 'az', 'àt'. If that is the order you need, then all is fine.

Comment: There are multiple versions of collation rules that can create the alphabetical order you specified, but each of those will sort a set of words differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the code provided. It was an issue with reading the text file. [Actual Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77480510/read-text-file-outputs-incorrect-data)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you have a character in `keys` that is not in `alphabet`.

You can change `sortA` to handle such cases instead of throwing an error:

```
def sortA(l, alphabet="AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"):
    def get_value(char):
        if char in alphabet:
            return alphabet.index(char)
        else:
            return len(alphabet)
    returnVal = sorted(l, key=lambda word: [get_value(c) for c in word])
    return returnVal
```

Ofc, you could always print `keys` and see if its value isn't what it is supposed to be..

---

#### Edit:

If I use the list you gave in the comments and change `sortA` function to print all the characters that are not in your `alphabet` like so:

```
def sortA(l, alphabet="AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"):
    def get_value(char):
        if char in alphabet:
            return alphabet.index(char)
        else:
            print("Character not in alphabet:", char)
            return len(alphabet)
    returnVal = sorted(l, key=lambda word: [get_value(c) for c in word])
    return returnVal


keys =  ['æovʌn', 'É¯aÊƒoid', 'dfsÊƒia']
keys = sortA(keys, "æǽaàbdyýeéfgiíʒklmnŋΩΏoóøǿɤprʃsþðtʊuúʌvɯjz")

print(keys)
```

I get:

```
Character not in alphabet: É
Character not in alphabet: ¯
Character not in alphabet: Ê
Character not in alphabet: ƒ
Character not in alphabet: Ê
Character not in alphabet: ƒ
['æovʌn', 'dfsÊƒia', 'É¯aÊƒoid']
```

This could give you an idea of the characters you missed in your customized `alphabet`.

Comment: All these characters: `É¯ÊƒÊƒ` are not supposed to be there

Comment: So what is the original input of `keys`?

Comment: @nolka `keys = ['mægnʌ', 'gløsΩs', 'leksikΩs']` and I get `['leksikΩs', 'magnÊŒ', 'glÃ¸sÎ©s']`

Comment: When I run `keys = ['mægnʌ', 'gløsΩs', 'leksikΩs']` I get `['gløsΩs', 'leksikΩs', 'mægnʌ']`

Comment: When I run `keys = ['mægnʌ', 'gløsΩs', 'leksikΩs']` I get `['gløsΩs', 'leksikΩs', 'mægnʌ']` without the rest of the code also so the problem must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What font are you using if you view your text input in an editor? What font are you using when you view Python console output? If you comment out for call to `sortA`, how does the input data if you never transform it?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to develop collation rules to use. If you are on a system that uses gLibC, then it would be possible to create a custom locale with collation rules. Alternatively, it would be possible to use PyICU, if ICU4C is available on your platform:

The following rules are a rough draft based on OP and comments:

```
[strength 2]
&[before 1]a<æ
&d<y
&i<ʒ
&n<ŋ<Ω
&o<ø<ɤ
&r<ʃ
&s<þ<ð<t<ʊ
&u<ʌ
&v<ɯ<j
```

Then create a random list of letters in the alphabet:

```py
import random
alphabet = "æǽaàbdyýeéfgiíʒklmnŋΩΏoóøǿɤprʃsþðtʊuúʌvɯjz"
random_alphabet = random.sample(alphabet,len(alphabet))
print(random_alphabet)
# ['ʌ', 'l', 'Ω', 'k', 'd', 'é', 'ð', 'e', 'þ', 'i', 'n', 'm', 'ǽ', 'ʃ', 'í', 'ʒ', 'f', 't', 'z', 'ú', 'p', 'ɤ', 'g', 'y', 'ŋ', 's', 'ǿ', 'Ώ', 'j', 'æ', 'o', 'b', 'v', 'ʊ', 'à', 'ý', 'u', 'a', 'ø', 'ɯ', 'ó', 'r']
```

Create a collator instance for sorting:

```py
import icu
rules = "[strength 2]&[before 1]a<æ&d<y&i<ʒ&n<ŋ<Ω&o<ø<ɤ&r<ʃ&s<þ<ð<t<ʊ&u<ʌ&v<ɯ<j"
collator = icu.RuleBasedCollator(rules)
```

Then sort the list:

```py
sorted_alphabet = sorted(random_alphabet, key=collator.getSortKey)
alphabet == "".join(sorted_alphabet)
# True
print("".join(sorted_alphabet))
# æǽaàbdyýeéfgiíʒklmnŋΩΏoóøǿɤprʃsþðtʊuúʌvɯjz
```

**Edit:**

There are key differences between the sort routine in the OP and the one in this answer regarding the weighting of characters in the alphabet. The OP's code gives all letters of the alphabet equal weighting, in terms of collation, this means that each letter has primary strength. In my answer, letters with diacritics are given secondary strength. This will result in a different sort order that that produced by the function as defined in OP:

```py
def sortA(l, alphabet="AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"):
    returnVal = sorted(l, key=lambda word: [alphabet.index(c) for c in word])
    return returnVal
data = ["ba", "àt", "az"]
sortA(data, "æǽaàbdyýeéfgiíʒklmnŋΩΏoóøǿɤprʃsþðtʊuúʌvɯjz")
# ['az', 'àt', 'ba']
```

Using the collator defined above:

```py
sorted(data, key=collator.getSortKey)
# ['àt', 'az', 'ba']
```

`sortA()` would be the equivalent of

```py
[strength 2]
&[before 1]a<æ<ǽ
&a<à
&d<y
&e<é
&i<í<ʒ
&n<ŋ<Ω
&o<ó<ø<ɤ
&r<ʃ
&s<þ<ð<t<ʊ
&u<ú<ʌ
&v<ɯ<j
```

where every character has primary weight. Two different sets of rules, each will sort the alphabet the same, but will sort words differently.

Comment: The collation rules may need updating, form the alphabet order, it is difficult to tell if some of the extended Latin and Greek characters have primary or secondary strength n collation weights. I am assuming primary in the question.