# Read text file outputs incorrect data

Tags: python, file-handling

[Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77477528/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-words-in-alphabetical-order-from-a-custom-alphabet)

I have been trying to sort a list of words based off a custom alphabet: `æǽaàbdyýeéfgiíʒklmnŋΩΏoóøǿɤprʃsþðtʊuúʌvɯjz` . The program was outputting random nonsense that I didn't put in, and I decided it was a problem with reading the file.

When I read the text file:

```
mægnʌ
d
d

gløsΩs
d
d
```

I get:

```
magnÊŒ
d
d

glÃ¸sÎ©s
d
d
```

And it causes an error later in the program.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with [encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: `and I decided it was a problem with reading the file` I'm glad you decided that when you forgot to specify an encoding ... `with open('myfile.txt' , 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f`. I'm not sure what your `custom alphabet` is but as long as its characters are supported in an encoding, you should be good to go, otherwise you should create your own encoding (with blackjack and ... )

Comment: @OM222O Custom alphabet is `æǽaàbdyýeéfgiíʒklmnŋΩΏoóøǿɤprʃsþðtʊuúʌvɯjz `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the characters in your custom alphabet are a part of Unicode, then you can open the file with ‘UTF-8’ encoding, like @OM222O suggested. Modified code:

```
with open(YOUR_FILEPATH, encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    print(file.readlines())
```

You have to replace YOUR_FILEPATH with your file path. Using the encoding will ensure that the characters are printed correctly. The ‘with’ statement is an efficient way of opening a file because the file is closed on exiting the ‘with’ statement.

PS: I think your alphabet is a Nordic alphabet, so Unicode encoding should work pretty well.